# using git read-tree without a work tree

Tags: git, git-plumbing

I am trying to create a commit history using git plumbing commands with a bare repo. I can create commits with a single unnamed tree object containing blobs, but I cannot figure out how to get this unnamed tree object to contain other tree objects.

I tried using `git read-tree --prefix=tree_name tree_sha`
and it tells me: `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`

I tried using `git mktree` (like it is shown on [this page](http://alx.github.io/gitbook/7_raw_git.html))
like this: `cat ../info.txt | git mktree`

info.txt being a file containing 1 line:

```
040000 tree aa8c07e1371022a183b011d5d41517ef54780a17    test_tree
```

and it tells me:

```
fatal: input format error: 040000 tree aa8c07e1371022a183b011d5d41517ef54780a17    tree_name
```

Can anyone tell me a way to create and name trees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need four spaces instead of one between the hash and test_tree. If it still doesn't work try a tab.

```
040000 tree aa8c07e1371022a183b011d5d41517ef54780a17    test_tree
```

Comment: I am not sure if I pasted it here wrong, but I did have 4 spaces between the sha and the tree name (test_tree). I double checked and tried again, I still got the same error.

Comment: I know how Git works internally, but I don't know what most of the git commands do. You could try doing it manually, but that's not so easy to do.

Comment: I apologize, when I tested this before I had assumed that I was initially using a tab between the hash and the tree name, so I thought that that wasn't the issue, turns out it was. replacing the 4 spaces between aa8c07e1371022a183b011d5d41517ef54780a17 and test_tree I had with a tab fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume a tree with hash `aa8c07e1371022a183b011d5d41517ef54780a17` already exists in your repo?  If not, `git mktree` will fail.  Also, do you have a trailing newline in `info.txt`?  My reading of the docs suggests this is also required.

I have successfully used `git mktree` like this:

```
$ cat tree.txt
040000 tree 4d5fcadc293a348e88f777dc0920f11e7d71441c    foo

$ git mktree < tree.txt
0a7f38a609340d0b8eede2f6debf8bad4191738f
```

Where the first two spaces are spaces, and the third is a tab, and with a trailing newline.  If in doubt, run `git ls-tree` and examine its output, possibly with `xxd`.

Comment: I finally got it to work! It turns out that the issue was that I was using 4 spaces instead of a tab between the hash and the name(I need to apologize to ThePyroEagle, since he already suggested this). Also if there is a trailing newline in the file there is an odd artifact that occurs when I look at the tree using "git cat-file -p <insertTreeHashHere>". If I used mktree on the file with a trailing newline the trees name is listed as: "test_tree\r" (with quotations and a /r), but if there is no trailing newline it looks normal: test_tree (no quotations or /r)

Comment: Sounds like you've got a Windows newline (`\r\n`) rather than a Unix one (`\n`).  Glad you could fix it, maybe give upvotes as well as accepting the answer?

Comment: As soon as I have at least 15 rep I intend to upvote your answer as well as his. Also double thank you because your comment about it being a windows newline was correct and you helped me fix another issue.

Comment: Well if that tree existed, then there's absolutely no point in adding *it* again. If it already exists, chances are the content are the exact same.

Comment: @ThePyroEagle, the tree I was asking about was the one being put as a sub-tree of the new tree, not the new tree itself.